# Integration with piecewise functions

Tags: python

In my computation, I need the following numerically in Python.

[image]

z has a range `[0, 4]`.

From the help of Andrey Tyukin, I wrote the codes.

However, I can't determine the following codes.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried computing `k0(z)` for which `k0/10 <= z <= (k0+1)/10` (handling edge cases as appropriate)? Then you can replace the indicator and the sum by a single term with the appropriate `k0`.

Comment: Did you really mean `[k/10, (k+1)/10]` (closed on both sides)? This seems to give weird jumps on the single point where two neighboring intervals intersect. Even though the set with weird jumps has measure zero, it could break numerical integration pretty badly.

Comment: You probably should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting before continuing. And please don't post images of code: they are impossible to work with without retyping everything from scratch (I've heard about optical character recognition, but I don't believe in it). Even in the image, the code looks as if it shouldn't work because of indentation issues.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you can get the only relevant `k` from `z` simply by `int(z * 10)`. Then, you have to make sure that the function is `0` outside of the interval `[0, 4]`. The rest is just evaluation of a simple polynomial. Try something like this:

```
def f(z):
  k = int(z * 10)
  if k < 0 or k > 40: return 0.0
  return (
    ((2 * k + 1) / 20.0 - ((k + 1)**4 - k ** 4) / 1000.0) * 
    (z - k / 10.0) +
    (k*k/200.0 - k**4 / 10000.0)
  )
```

I assume that there is actually a typo in your formula, and you actually want characteristic functions on `[k/10, (k+1)/10)` (closed, open), instead of `[k/10, (k+1)/10]` (closed, closed). The discontinuous jumps between the intervals wouldn't matter while integrating, but it feels as if they shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: By the way, the following code is true for the integration? I just change given functions a little bit.                                                                                     
from sympy import Integral, symbols, exp
x,y,z = symbols('x,y,z') 
def f(x) :
  k = int(x * 10)
  if k < 0 or k > 40: return 0.0
  return (
    ((2 * k + 1) / 20.0 - ((k + 1)**4 - k ** 4) / 1000.0) * 
    (x - k / 10.0) + (k*k/200.0 - k**4 / 10000.0)) 
def g(y) : 
 return exp(-y**2-0.5*f(z+y)-0.5*f(z-y))
 print(Integral(g, (y,-3.2,3.2)).doit())

Comment: What do you mean by "code is true"? It implements the first function `f` that you sketched in the formula. I assume that you want to feed it into some numerical integration procedure.

Comment: @Chriskim That comment looks a bit dense. If this is supposed to be clarification of the original question, you should use the little gray 'edit' button in the lower left corner to update the question. Comments don't preserve formatting so crucial for python code.

Comment: @Anrey Tyukin     OK. I will changed the original question.